# VB - connect to local SQL server and load data to table from excel

Tags: mysql, sql-server, excel, vb.net, database-connection

I want to connect with VB code to my local SQL Server and load data into a table from my Excel file. This is what I got so far with my code that is incomplete. The field of the table (me_table) I created in the SQL database are z, ad, ag, retd, to, wg and in Excel sheet1 are column with data that reflects the field in the table. Thanks

Please advise

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1
    Dim myconnection As SqlConnection
    Dim mycommand As SqlCommand
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader
    Dim ra As Integer

    Sub Main()

        Dim connectionString As String = "Server=DER7D;Database=testDB;User Id=DER7D\Der;Password="
        myconnection = New SqlConnection("server=DER7D;uid=root;pwd=;database=simple")
        'you need to provide password for sql server
        myconnection.Open()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Sounds like the first step is to load the excel data

Comment: Heres a link for getting data from Excel sheet: http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_2007_open_file.htm

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information and link. I am looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not taking good design into consideration, this is what you need. Just update the SqlConnection string. If you decide you want to use multiple sheets, just add them to the worksheets variable.

```
Private Sub SaveDataFromSpreadsheet()
Dim filePath = "directory\me_spreadsheet.xlsx"
Dim connectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;", filePath)
Dim worksheets As New List(Of String)() From {
  "Sheet1"
}

For i As Integer = 0 To worksheets.Count - 1
  Dim worksheetName As String = worksheets(i)
  Dim adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", worksheetName), connectionString)
  Dim ds = New DataSet()

  adapter.Fill(ds, "me_table")

  Dim data As DataTable = ds.Tables("me_table")

  For x As Integer = 0 To data.Rows.Count - 1
    Dim z As String = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Rows(x).ItemArray(0).ToString()), "", data.Rows(x).ItemArray(0).ToString())
    Dim ad As String = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Rows(x).ItemArray(1).ToString()), "", data.Rows(x).ItemArray(1).ToString())
    Dim ag As String = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Rows(x).ItemArray(2).ToString()), "", data.Rows(x).ItemArray(2).ToString())
    Dim retd As String = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Rows(x).ItemArray(3).ToString()), "", data.Rows(x).ItemArray(3).ToString())
    Dim wg As String = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Rows(x).ItemArray(4).ToString()), "", data.Rows(x).ItemArray(4).ToString())

    Using myconnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=Your-Server;Initial Catalog=me_database;Integrated Security=True")
      myconnection.Open()
      Dim mycommand As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO me_Table(z, ad, ag, retd, wg) VALUES(@z, @ad, @ag, @retd, @wg)", myconnection)

      mycommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@z", z))
      mycommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ad", ad))
      mycommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@ag", ag))
      mycommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@retd", retd))
      mycommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@wg", wg))

      mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
      myconnection.Close()
    End Using

  Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", worksheetName), connectionString)    ----........ thanks for the code, but there is an error with OleDbDataAdapter is not defined.

Comment: I found the problem need to use Import System.Data.Oledb, I am looking at the rest of the code. Thanks

Comment: very nice code, it work. Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it. :-)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again Krob, I noticed it has worked in my window 7 and my sql server 2014, however this code doesn't work for window 10, office 360 and sql sever 2016.  Error with code adapter.fill(da, "zipco").  Error message the Microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: no problem. You need to install the components. Any one of these should work. 
'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50040'
'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39358' 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255'

Comment: actually I had installed the access 2016 runtime and it didn't work, thanks

Comment: Thank you KRob, I installed the 2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components on my Window 10 machine and it works. It seems to me that Office 365 lacks a component, driver, needed to connect between SQL server and excel while office 2007 has it. So is solved and sorry I am new to VB. :)